# typescript mapped types multiple types

Tags: typescript, types, dynamic, nested, mapped-types

I have 2 types:

```
type UserForm = 'student' | 'teacher';
type FormFields = 'name' | 'age' | 'email';
```

what I want to achieve:

```
interface Form {
  form: {
    studentName: string;
    studentAge: string;
    studentEmail: string;
    teacherName: string;
    teacherAge: string;
    teacherEmail: string;
  }
}
```

I know it can be done "manually", like this, but it's not necessary linked to the UserForm type

```
interface {
  form: {
    [K in FormFields as `student${Capitalize<K>}`]: string
  } & {
    [K in FormFields as `teacher${Capitalize<K>}`]: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter way to achieve this behavior would look like this:

```
interface Form {
  form: {
    [K in `${UserForm}${Capitalize<FormFields>}`]: string
  }
}
```

Key remapping does not seem to be necessary here. We can simply use both `UserForm` and `FormFields` in the template literal type and the mapped type will use it to construct a union of all permutations.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgMQPaILZQLxQORzACuAJhAHbB5QA++wEAhgMYAWSeA3ALABQokKGkzIAlhAA2JODnzlGGCNTp5GAcyW18EDI1ESufPqMpIAZi2jCsAbz5QoZ9BgBcUO7wcOA2gGkoJlAABgAkNvBI1gC+YQDCjGCiwIwSogBeEAA81mKS0gB8UUEAum6EiCZq9lBRfFFAA)

Comment: I was close, I tried:
```form: {
    [K in `${UserForm}${Capitalize<K>}`]: string
 }```
but that throws an error, ty.

Comment: This union interpolation can also be written using the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) type utility as [`Record<\`${UserForm}${Capitalize<FormFields>}\`, string>`](https://tsplay.dev/w2pzrm)